# Add CSS class to every image

Tags: images, css

I want to add a CSS class "myimg" to every image both inside and outside of a post. What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 10):

```
function add_image_class($class){
    $class .= ' additional-class';
    return $class;
}
add_filter('get_image_tag_class','add_image_class');
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to use this j query function like this in header file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("img").addClass("myimg")
});
```

Comment: is there a way to do this via PHP or a WP function rather than JS?

Comment: The better way is not php or wordpress for all images.