# How to add a CSS class to every image in a Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, images, filters, css

I'm trying to add a CSS class to every image in a custom post type.

I've found [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108831/add-css-class-to-every-image), to add a class to every image in general:

```
function add_image_class($class){
    $class .= ' additional-class';
    return $class;
}
add_filter('get_image_tag_class','add_image_class');
```

How would I build on this, so that it only applies to a custom post type?

Answer (score 5):

Combining the answer here by @cjcj with the code in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/22166/92868), the code that works for me outside the loop, in functions.php is:

```
// Add ability to check for custom post type outside the loop. 
function is_post_type($type){
    global $wp_query;
    if($type == get_post_type($wp_query->post->ID)) return true;
    return false;
}

// Add class to every image in 'wpse' custom post type.
function add_image_class($class){
    if ('wpse' == is_post_type()){
        $class .= ' additional-class';
    }
    return $class;
}
add_filter('get_image_tag_class','add_image_class');
```

Answer (score 3):

The function [`get_post_type`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type/) returns the type of the current post, so supposing you want to add this class only to a post type called 'wpse' you should include a conditional like this:

```
function wpse237573_add_image_class($class){
    if ('wpse' == get_post_type()) $class .= ' additional-class';
    return $class;
}
add_filter('get_image_tag_class','wpse237573_add_image_class');
```

Comment: Thank you @cjbj. This works, but only within in the loop. I want to put the code in my functions.php, where it's not working like this. But you helped me in the right direction and I combined your answer with [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/22166/92868) to a working solution. I'll share it as a new answer below.