# Add custom CSS class to product images

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, images

I would like to add a custom CSS when displaying product images. E.g. when calling the `woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail` function.

I've tried solutions like this: [Add CSS class to every image](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108831/add-css-class-to-every-image?newreg=07e540a9023844438b5f189e5657f524) but they don't work. The class only gets added to images that are not related to products.

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 1):

If it's still relevant, you can add a class to the product thumbnail the following way.

```
function loop_product_custom_thumbnail() {
  echo the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'your-class-name'));
}
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10);
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'loop_product_custom_thumbnail', 10 );
```